# Running not the same app I'm debugging?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, debugging

Weird stuff happening. I'm developing an iOS app under iOS 4.2 using Xcode 3. I have the same app in two different folders and they have different xib files (because of two different languages of resources). When I'm firing up to study console logs I'm getting the other one app on device - not the one I have opened at the time... sometimes it even gets weirder: I'm starting app A, but I see on my iPhone (4S btw) intro from version A and menu from B... Meanwhile both were succesfully installed onto device, so I can manually use them separately - but not while running from Xcode.

edit: these two apps have different bundle id and names

Comment: I know XCode doesn't properly handle deleted assets, including nibs/xibs. Have you deleted any nibs/xibs?

Comment: I might have deleted some localized xibs, but still shouldn't it take the only one existing?

Comment: When you delete a xib from the file, XCode doesn't actually delete it from the device, so if the localized one takes precedence (which it probably does), the runtime will use it. Delete the app from the device, then clean the project before rebuilding it.

Answer (score 0):

two things:

1. Clean before building (Shift-Cmd-K)
2. The reason the other version opens on your iPhone when you build your app is that they are both sharing the same Bundle Identifier (CFBundleIdentifier) in info.plist

Comment: nope, I had A installed (closed project), then opened B and started to debug B, wich fired up on device project A